# Autocomplete primeng with object binding angular 4

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using primeng autocomplete, my suggetions is a objects list of cities.
This is my model:

```
export class City {

  'sid': string;
  'createdDate': any;
  'lastModifiedDate': any;
  'lastModifiedBy': string;
  'name': string;
  'province': string;
  'region': string;

}
```

This is my **component.html**

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selected.city"
                    [suggestions]="suggestions" field="name" delay=800
                    (completeMethod)="search($event)"
                    (onSelect)="setCity(selected.city)"
                    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"> <ng-template
                    let-city pTemplate="item">
                <div class="ui-helper-clearfix"
                    style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5">
                    <div style="font-size: 15px; float: left; margin: 2px 2px 0 0">{{city.name}}
                        ({{city.province}})</div>
                    <div style="font-size: 12px; float: left; margin: 3px 3px 0 0">{{city.region}}</div>
                </div>
                </ng-template> </p-autoComplete>
```

and this is the method setCity() called in onSelect

```
setCity(value) {

    this.selected.city = value.name;
    console.log(value.name);
  }
```

The component shows suggestions list correctly but now when I select one of the suggestions I see the autocomplete input field empty, is there some binding problem?

Comment: Click all the tags below your question, read the description, do you all use them?

Comment: ok sorry, tag unused deleted

Comment: Try Either remove this line this.selected.city = value.name; or use this instead this.selected.city = value; inside your method setCity(value). Also try calling method correctly at line (onSelect)="setCity(selected.city)" replace this wit h  (onSelect)="setCity($value)"